# Testing and verifying an Angular2+ build

Tags: unit-testing, automation, angular6

I am having an Angular2+ application.

I have done some unit testing with Karma-Jasmine. But my assumption is that this is only for dev enviroment(pre production).

I am looking for a testing framework through which the "dist" folder build can be verified(components, web services, etc...)? so that once the build is taken, some script that do login, should able to verify the response object for login service etc...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are asking how to do end-to-end testing to your application in addition to unit tests. In that case Selenium and more modern Cypress are what you are looking for.

Comment: If i use Selenium, can i test the webservice response? I would like to test the entire application including the webservices...

Comment: When you want to test your rest api etc. it’s integration testing. E.g. using supertest or whatever your backend implementation is. End to end tests of course tests your service responses indirectly but are slower. There is a concept called test pyramid to check what you want to test and how much effort to put on each layer.